# how to force class component rerender

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component which receives a list of beds.

I then pass this list of beds down to a bed component that shows the beds.

Some of the beds are occupied and others are available.

I have a button on the occupied beds to enable you to swap beds. So sending the patient to a different bed.

It all works well except for the fact that the screen does not update.

I have added a variable in the redux state which I can track that it changed, but the components stil does not update or refresh.

I have added the `connect` to the bottom to connect with redux store.

Im not sure how else to re-render the component

Its a big piece of code so not sure what I can post here to help with the question.

The only thing I can say is we normally use redux-forms and its relatively easy to detect changes from there and to run `initialize`, but because this is a situation without a form Im not sure how to force a rerender.

Comment: In theory, with react if you show in html a variable and that variable will be updated (in redux or in local state using useState hook) component will be authomatically re-rendered. Have you tried to put a console.log in useEffect with that variable in deps list in component that is not re-rendering?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Sorry, but its a Class Component so no hooks.

Comment: same question but with `componentDidUpdate` instead of useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a component to update by updating the components internal state or by updating the key value on a component. Which will likely involve updating state in a level above it.

```js
<Component key={someVariable} />
```